# How to reverse the legend order in a plot created with sjPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I use the data of mtcars to build a `lmer` model as below.
The problem is that when I use `sjplot::plot_model` to plot marginal effect plot, I found the order of legend is reversed. The expected order is that the low value is at the bottom and the large value is at the top. Could you help me resolve it?  Thanking everyone who pays attention to this issue.

```
mdl <- lmer(disp~mpg:wt+vs+(1|cyl) , data = mtcars)

sjplot::plot_model(mdl,type = 'pred',terms = c("mpg [all]","wt"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are basically dealing with a `ggplot` you could reverse the order of the legend via `guide_legend`:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggplot2)

mdl <- lmer(disp~mpg:wt+vs+(1|cyl) , data = mtcars)

sjPlot::plot_model(mdl,type = 'pred',terms = c("mpg [all]","wt")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]